# Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым в предложении при наличии отрицательной частицы НЕ

Tags: тире

В предложении *Гринев не героическая личность , он просто честный служака* тире между подлежащим и сказуемым нужно? В правиле написано, что при отрицательной частице *не* не ставится тире, но здесь же частица относится к прилагательному(влияет ли это на постановку тире)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тире не обязательно и в этом случае. Ограничений на зависимые слова нет.

В вашем случае НЕ перетягивает логическое ударение не на "личность", а на "героическая", но всё равно перетягивает, в связи с чем тире не обязательно. А при тире ударение остаётся на подлежащем — "Гринёв".

В связи с контекстом всё же лучше с ударением на "Гринёв" (с тире). Наверно, это связано с пафосом (отрицается героичность).
Если до этого говорили, что он героическая личность (а кто-то отрицает), то лучше без тире.